# Office 365 Security and Compliance Center alerts api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

Does anybody know if there is a rest API to the office 365 Security and Compliance center that can give me back any alerts raised by the Alert Policy?

It seems that there are some PowerShell cmdlets that allow the creation of new Alert Policies, but I would like to pull down the alerts generated by these policies (preferably without using PowerShell).

Maybe this is on the road-map for a future Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

Office365 security alerts are not yet supported, but this should be possible for Microsoft security products using the Public Preview of Graph Security API - aka.ms/graphsecurityapi.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Graph Security API only has access to the following(now GA).](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Security-Privacy-and-Compliance/The-Microsoft-Graph-Security-API-is-now-generally-available/ba-p/254128)

Microsoft Graph Security API to easily access alerts from the following security solutions:

Azure Active Directory Identity Protection,
Azure Information Protection,
Azure Security Center,
Microsoft Cloud App Security,
Microsoft Intune,
Windows Defender ATP, and 
Office 365 ATP and Azure ATP **(coming soon)**